# Neo4j - Reference a node in the properties of a relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm wondering if the property of a relationship between two nodes can reference another node. I'm trying to see if I can visualize Cisco ACLs with Neo4j, so I've got some data that looks like this:

> object-group network Server_Group_A
>
> network-object host 1.2.3.4
>
> network-object host 2.3.4.5
>
> network-object host 3.4.5.6
>
> object-group network Server_Group_B
>
> network-object host 4.3.2.1
>
> network-object host 5.4.3.2
>
> network-object host 6.5.4.3
>
> object-group service Port_Group_A tcp
>
> port-object eq 80
>
> port-object eq 443
>
> access-list Some_Interface extended permit tcp object-group Server_Group_A object-group Server_Group_B object-group Port_Group_A

So far, I've been building out everything in Cypher like this:

(`Server1` :Server {IP:'1.2.3.4'}),

...etc...

(`Server_Group_A` :ObjectGroup {Name:'Server_Group_A'}),

(`Server_Group_B` :ObjectGroup {Name:'Server_Group_B'}),

(`Port_Group_A` :PortGroup {Name:'Server_Group_B'}),

(`Port_80` :PortObject {Port:'80'}),

(`Port_443` :PortObject {Port:'443'}),

(`Server1`)-[:`MemberOf` ]->(`Server_Group_A`)

...etc...

(`Port_80`)-[:`MemberOf` ]->(`Port_Group_A`)

...etc...

When it comes to expressing the relationship between Server_Group_A and Server_Group_B to match the ACL, is it possible for me to have the Port_Group_A node be one of the properties of the relationship? I've tried this, but I get a type error, which I was sort of expecting:

(`Server_Group_A`)-[:`ConnectedTo` {Ports:[`Port_Group_A`]}]->(`Server_Group_B`)

If this isn't possible in the way I'm hoping it is, does anyone have any recommendations as to how they would approach this?

Answer (score 0):

A property value cannot be a node.

But it *could* be the node's unique identifier (for example, its `Name` property, if it is unique). But to get that node would require a more complex query (and may be less efficient).

Instead, you can "reify" the `ConnectedTo` relationship by turning it into a `Connection` node. For example:

```
(Server_Group_A)-[:HAS_OUTPUT_CONNECTION]->(c:Connection)<-[:HAS_INPUT_CONNECTION]-(Server_Group_B)
(c)-[:USES_PORT_GROUP]->(Port_Group_A])
```

Comment: I was thinking about this approach as well, utilizing a separate node that everything connects to in order to get around this. I'll give it a shot and see how it looks, thanks!